# prevent duplicated database value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve data from database and assign it in variables, but the problem I face is the variable get the first row data and then duplicate it, for example

if I have four rows with different values:

```
id  name
--------
1 - a
2 - b
3 - c
4 - d
```

when I assign name column to a variable and add it to a label the result will be like this:

```
id  name
--------
1 - a
2 - a
3 - a
4 - a
```

here is my code:

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  CssClass="datatable" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:mj.resource, req_category%>" 
             SortExpression="category_id">
           <ItemTemplate >
               <asp:Label ID="category_id" runat="server" 
                    text="<%# Variable_category %>"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs code:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection connectionmjh = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= DESKTOP-U9437PU; initial Catalog = Mydb; Integrated Security =True;");
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT category_table.category_id, category_table.category_type_en, category_table.category_type_ar, priority_table.priority_id, priority_table.priority_type_en, priority_table.priority_type_ar, requests_table.stat_id, stat_table.stat_type_en, stat_table.stat_type_ar 
                                                     FROM requests_table 
                                                     INNER JOIN stat_table ON requests_table.stat_id = stat_table.stat_id 
                                                     INNER JOIN priority_table ON priority_table.priority_id = requests_table.priority_id 
                                                     INNER JOIN category_table ON requests_table.category_id = category_table.category_id 
                                                     WHERE requests_table.user_name=" + name2, connectionmjh))
        {
            connectionmjh.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Variable_category = reader[1].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //error handling...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try: Change the values as per your ids. Exception handling has been omitted:

```
    var values = new List<string>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      values.add(reader.GetString(1));
    }

    int i = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridViewIdHere.Rows)
    {
        ((Label)row.FindControl("category_id")).Text = values[i];
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: what does rdr mean ?

Comment: thanks Gauravsa thats exactly what I was looking for, but I have a little problem when I click on the header to sort the rows in the gridview the label value become invisible.

Comment: i think when u click on the header, the page_load is called. i think you need to do if(!IsPostback)...

Comment: can you post another question, as this is a separate issue. lemme know and i can post a response.

Answer (score -1):

just an idea, the error is not here :

```
reader[1].ToString();
```

increment the [1].

Add `int i = 0;` before while and add i++ in the while and change [1] by [i]